# Do I need to install Package Dependencies when using PackageReference

Tags: c#, nuget, visual-studio-2017

So I used to use the old `packages.config` method of installing nugets which worked by installing any dependencies when installing a package: i.e.

- Package 1

  - Dependency 1
  - Dependency 2

I have now changed to use `PackageReference` but noticed as I was installing "Package 1" it would not automatically install the dependencies. As I wasn't sure I went and installed "Depdendency 1" and "Dependency 2" manually

Do I need to manually install "Depndendency 1" and "Dependency 2" when using `PackageReference`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is simply **no**, you should not need to manually install the dependencies.

There have been a few changes and performance improvements in the recent VS 2017 and MSBuild work. There's some good information on what this means [here](https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html):

> In the past, if your project referenced package A, which in-turn referenced packages B, C and D, you would see all of them listed as your dependencies. With Transitive Package Restore, NuGet dynamically resolves dependencies giving you an uncluttered view of the packages you care about.

That explains the "missing" package references. If you're interested in the "missing" files themselves, there's more information on that too:

> Solution-local packages folders are no longer used – Packages are now resolved against the user’s cache at %userdata%.nuget, rather than a solution specific packages folder. This makes PackageReference perform faster and consume less disk space by using a shared folder of packages on your workstation.

The reason I said *should* not need to is that there is a known [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481) around this area when mixing .NET Standard and .NET Framework.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the second quoted paragraph means, but my VS2017 projects very much still do create and curate a `packages` folder, with all the `.dll` files in per-package subfolders. (And, I think, luckily so, given that I'm relying on some tools to be in that spot that are called by my build scripts ... unless those are somehow treated differently, anyway.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper You need to [opt-in](https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html#what-about-other-project-types-that-are-not-net-core) to this new format, using either a .NET Standard/.NET Core project or with the [`RestoreProjectStyle`](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4488) element.

Comment: Ah, in that case, I can confirm this. Good to know that I might have to adapt my build scripts then to point to the new location.